# How to implement WS-Security with JAX-WS in Eclipse

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws, ws-security

Could anyone give me a basic tutorial about setup WS-Security SOAP with JAX-WS by using Eclipse tool. I found plenty of tut but they setup the security via xml file. That really drive me confused, because since I use JAX-WS in Eclipse there is no such xml file to modified.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use SSL?What do you expect do gain as extra by using `WS-Security`?

Comment: coz its a part of requirement